# Error al obtener registros que tenga la misma cantidad de llamadas foráneas de un campo de la misma tabla

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Lo que se quiere hacer es devolver un listado con todos los nombres de los fabricantes que tienen el mismo número de productos que el fabricante `Panasonic`, tomando en cuenta que están las `tablas` `producto` y `fabricante`, donde producto tiene la `llave foránea` `fabricante_id`. He estado intentando con esta `consulta`, pero da error al intentar comparar las `subconsultas`:

```
SELECT f.nombre
FROM fabricante AS f INNER JOIN producto AS p on f.id = p.fabricante_id
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(p.id) FROM fabricante AS f INNER JOIN producto as p 
on f.id = p.fabricante_id GROUP BY p.fabricante_id) = 
(SELECT COUNT(p.id) FROM fabricante AS f INNER JOIN producto as p on 
f.id = p.fabricante_id WHERE f.nombre = 'Panasonic' GROUP BY 
p.fabricante_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Josué podrías intentar con:

```
SELECT fabricante.nombre,producto.nombre FROM fabricante
INNER JOIN producto ON id_fabricante=id_producto
WHERE f.nombre='Panasonic'
```

Comment: Gracias por el intento Edgar, pero tu consulta solo me devuelve los productos relacionados con Panasonic, lo que intento hacer es, como panasonic tiene 2 productos relacionados, samsung y huawei tambien tienen 2 productos relacionados, quiero listar esos fabricantes porque tienen la misma cantidad de productos relacionados

Comment: ¿Y por qué esto funciona?

Comment: Ya encontre la forma, con esta consulta: SELECT T2.nombre
FROM (SELECT COUNT(p.id) as numero FROM fabricante AS f INNER JOIN producto AS p ON f.id = p.fabricante_id WHERE f.id = 11 GROUP BY f.id) AS T1 
INNER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(p.id) as numero, f.nombre FROM fabricante AS f INNER JOIN producto AS p ON f.id = p.fabricante_id GROUP BY f.id) AS T2 on T2.numero = T1.numero